# Дизайн окна, без заголовка, и независимого от стиля windows

Tags: windows, winapi, c++

Хотелось бы создать приложение, окно в котором было бы независимо от стиля Windows, не имело бы заголовка, что-то вроде окон Winamp'a или Aimpa'a, или всплывающего окна avast'a, qip'a, но с иcпользованием С++ WinApi.
Есть ли какие то простые способы сделать это на С++ ?

Answer (score 6):

```
hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_APPWINDOW,
    "MyWindowClass",
    "Window Title",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
    x, y,
    cx, cy,
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
);
```

Если поэкспериментируйте с первым ([dwExStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) и четвертым ([dwStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) параметрами, получите стопятьсот видов самых разнообразных окон.

Answer (score 2):

Визуально убрать любую рамку можно переписав 2 сообщения: `WM_NCCALCSIZE` и `WM_NCPAINT` ( и на всякий случай - `WM_PRINT` и `WM_PRINTCLIENT`, чтобы уже совсем ни какими способами это окно нельзя было отрисовать в чужом контексте )

В обработчиках необходимо просто вернуть 0, не передавая обработку встроенному обработчику окна, обычно - `DefWindowsProc`.

Чтобы избежать реакции мыши на определенные служебные области окна, необходимо переписать `WM_NCHITTEST`, вернув ответ `HTCLIENT` аналогично, напрямую системе, не передавая обработку встроенному обработчику окна

Мышь следует изолировать от служебных зон из-за того, что некоторые служебные компоненты и функции могут заниматься отрисовкой напрямую в граф. контекст окна, минуя `WM_PAINT`, как например `DrawCaption` - в ответ на сообщение `WM_NCACTIVATE`, поэтому, этим служебным компонентам нужно просто не дать возможности себя проявить.

Но даже все эти способы не гарантируют 100% независимость от стилей окна, которые задаются при его создании, например: при подвисании какого-либо приложения (в том числе и Winamp'а), подсистема GUI создает служебное окно на месте окна повисшего приложения, чтобы дать пользователю возможность манипулировать им в такие моменты, и это окно не наследует Вашу процедуру, поэтому выглядит ровно таким, каким было задумано Microsoft.

Так что мой вам совет - используйте обычные стили и не заморачивайтесь на том, как обойти систему, это все равно что доказывать всем, что у вас под одеждой вместо кожи натянут дермантин.

Answer (score 1):

[CreateWindowEx](http://netcode.ru/cpp/?click=r-2379.php.htm) это создание стандартынх окон с разными стилями. 
В случаи с Aimp, там используются скины, можно посмотреть [здесь](http://www.realcoding.net/article/view/1602).

Comment: Рисование по окну и прикрепление региона не отменяет собственно создания окна: без рамки там и так далее.

Answer (score 0):

При использовании Borland'a, можно поставить окну (форме) в свойствах border=none. Тогда будет просто серый прямоугольник, без окантовки и кнопок управления окном.

Comment: В вопросе написано про WinAPI, и нет ничего про билдер.